# WindowBuilder en eclipse sale ventana cortada

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

Estoy empezando con eclipse y el plugin `WindowBuilder` y tengo un problema.
Creo un `JFrame` nuevo y en la pestaña `Design` me aparece la ventana cortada. He buscado por todas partes y no consigo arreglarlo. La ejecución la hace bien.

*La versión de Java es `JavaSE 1.8`.*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es por el ancho del la ventana que estás definiendo y tú máximo ancho del sistema operativo,

Entonces en la parte superior derecha, al nivel dónde está la barra de Windows builder puedes ajustar si ver el lienzo al 50% 75% etc, en se momento está con el system

Answer (score 0):

Me pasa lo mismo, para arreglarlo presiona la ventana principal o el "javax.swing.JFrame" y en la ventanilla de propiedades le das a "Show Advance Properties", esto desplegará varias opciones pero hay una que dice "extendedState" y esta configurada por defecto en "Normal", pero vas a seleccionar la opción "ICONIFIED" y ya podrás ver que se repliega la ventana.

[image: Imagen de como queda]